# How to get a browser's winid?

Tags: plugins, browser, gtk, npapi

I am working on a plugin for the webkit-kernel browser.
I need to embed a gtk window in the browser as a plugin.
But I found the browser does not call the `setwindow` method to give me the winid.
So, what can I do for that?

Platform:

- Ubuntu for ARM 11.10
- Chromium browser

Note that the browser does obey the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) rules.

Comment: the browser doesn't call setwindow at all?

Comment: yes.The Chromium does not call the setwindow function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're setting everything up correctly? In particular, I believe that chromium only supports XEmbed, so if you never set your plugin up to tell the browser that you support it it won't try to give you your window.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XEmbed_Extension_for_Mozilla_Plugins

Example: https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/X11/NpapiPluginX11.cpp -- search the file for "xembed" and you'll see where we're setting things up.